# Lucene: How to factor in similarity to original term?

Tags: java, search, nlp, lucene, tf-idf

Say someone searches for 'shoes', and I have two documents called 'clothes' and 'socks' and both are added as synonyms for 'shoes'.

Both would be ranked equally for this term, but I want 'socks' to be ranked higher than 'clothes'.

Lets say I have a function which takes two words and returns a numeric similarity score. E.g:

`similarity("shoes", "socks") = 0.8`

`similarity("shoes", "clothes") = 0.65`

How can I have that similarity score be fed to Lucene to tell it to rank `socks` higher than `clothes`?

I think ideally, what I want is to multiply the term frequency for each term by its similarity. E.g:

`tf('socks') * 0.8`

`tf('clothes) * 0.65`

That way, all the other workings of the lucene scoring formula stay the same, but synonym terms are just given more or less importance in proportion to their similarity to the original term.

Is this possible? Function queries? Extending default similarity?

Comment: I think this is what you may be looking for: [Synonyms Boost by Payload](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-9171).  More background [here](https://sease.io/2020/03/introducing-weighted-synonyms-in-apache-lucene.html). I have not used any of this (or even confirmed that it has made it into 8.5) - hence I'm only commenting, not answering.